# Removing text from the bookmarks strip of Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

How do I remove the text labels from the bookmarks bar in Google Chrome?

[image: screenshot of bookmarks bar]

All I really want is a row of favicons!

Comment: Getting started with firefox inside Chrome?

Comment: He imported his settings from Firefox ;-)

Comment: @Sam152 - In my defence, it wasn't a screenshot from my PC! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on the bookmark and hit edit, then just leave the name field blank.

Comment: You don't even need a space in there, just leave it blank.

Comment: Good point, updated.

Comment: Never really thought of that, good idea!

Comment: Watch out tho. If you use any bookmark extensions unnamed bookmarks can get lost.

Comment: Good luck doing this for >100 bookmarks.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer uses a plugin to do the works for me, this plugins is [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/io-bookbar-icon-only-book/olpcoijhnioeaopipiblnmjlckcbbfhm/related)

Comment: I cannot download today.